# Restart Azure Function automatically / trigger

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have few Azure functions. I've created Logic app to check status of functions and whenever they run failed it'll tell me via Monitor Alerts.

What I need to do now is create "something" that whenever any of function run has failed (basically when alert is triggered) it will restart them/it.

Any help?
Thanks